# Kubernetes OOM killer

Tags: kubernetes, oom

I have some questions regarding OOM killer,  for pods crossing their memory limit does kubernetes allow graceful shutdown before firing sigkill.
Second question is that does kubernetes immediately kill the pod or it only kills the pod if the node does not have enough memory

Answer (score 0):

Usually a OOM killer uses `sigkill` and not `sigterm`. Kubernetes uses the Linux kernel OOM killer. So if you want to know more about this, you may read about how the regular OOM killer of Linux works. It's possible to adjust its settings in a more favorable way.

You may read this excelent article here:

[Out-of-memory (OOM) in Kubernetes – Part 1: Intro and topics discussed](https://mihai-albert.com/2022/02/13/out-of-memory-oom-in-kubernetes-part-1-intro-and-topics-discussed/)

[Out-of-memory (OOM) in Kubernetes – Part 2: The OOM killer and application runtime implications](https://mihai-albert.com/2022/02/13/out-of-memory-oom-in-kubernetes-part-2-the-oom-killer-and-application-runtime-implications/)

[Out-of-memory (OOM) in Kubernetes – Part 3: Memory metrics sources and tools to collect them](https://mihai-albert.com/2022/02/13/out-of-memory-oom-in-kubernetes-part-3-memory-metrics-sources-and-tools-to-collect-them/)

[Out-of-memory (OOM) in Kubernetes – Part 4: Pod evictions, OOM scenarios and flows leading to them](https://mihai-albert.com/2022/02/13/out-of-memory-oom-in-kubernetes-part-4-pod-evictions-oom-scenarios-and-flows-leading-to-them/)